# Redux Object Not Updating in Component Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to open a menu on-click. On-click calls this.props.openMenu. Note that openMenu was put in props by mapDispatchToProps (called via connect on the component export), and I have confirmed using print statements that this works as intended. Once dispatched, my reducer takes the action and returns an object. The object is not appearing my component props, as I thought it would with mapStatetoProps. I think the problem might be that the object returned by my reducer is not being recognized by mapStateToProps in my component, and as a result, componentDidUpdate() is not triggering and the menu doesn't open? I am not mutating anything.

Update: After console.logging this.props.menu.action, I found that action IS actually being put into props. Now, this makes me think the issue is with my dispatch.

Here is my reducer:

```
// Reducer for Menu in HomeScreen.js

const initialState = {
  action: "",
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "OPEN_MENU":
      console.log("processing");
      console.log("state", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        action: "openMenu",
      };
    case "CLOSE_MENU":
      return {
        ...state,
        action: "closeMenu",
      };
    case "OPEN_ADD_GROUP":
      return {
        ...state,
        action: "openAddGroup",
      };
    case "CLOSE_ADD_GROUP":
      return {
        ...state,
        action: "closeAddGroup",
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "../components/MenuScreen";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { openMenu } from "../actions/menuaction";

Amplify.configure(amplify);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { action: state.action };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    openMenu: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: "OPEN_MENU",
      }),
  };
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.action != this.props.action) {
      this.toggleMenu();
    }
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    if (this.props.action == "openMenu") {
      Animated.timing(this.state.scale, {
        toValue: 0.9,
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.in(),
      }).start();
      Animated.spring(this.state.scale, {
        toValue: 0.5,
      }).start();

      StatusBar.setBarStyle("light-content", true);
    }

    if (this.props.action == "closeMenu") {
      Animated.timing(this.state.scale, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.in(),
      }).start();
      Animated.spring(this.state.scale, {
        toValue: 1,
      }).start();

      StatusBar.setBarStyle("dark-content", true);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.openMenu}>
      <Avatar source={require("../../assets/profilepic.jpg")} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Here is my configureStore:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import menureducer from "../reducers/menureducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      menu: menureducer,
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );

  return store;
};
```

Here is my App.js file:

```
const store = configureStore();
console.log("state: ", store.getState());

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Authentication />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(this.props.action)` in the HomeScreen component? It looks like your mapStateToProps should be adjusted `return {action: state.menu.action}` since in your combineReducers you called it `menu`.

Comment: Agree with `mapStateToProps` should return `{ action: state.menu.action }` based on the combined reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your `mapStateToProps` function

Let's try to log your state to see what you have.

See in `configureStore`

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      menu: menureducer,
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
```

You name it as `menu`

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { action: state.menu.action };
}
```